# How to trap the back and forward button and refresh using Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

This is for an online examination: I should trap the user to use the back and forward button from browser and also by refreshing the page when the user is already taking the exam.
Thanks in advance for your answers and responses.

Comment: I don't think you can, since that's a browser thing not a code thing (that I know). However, look into the lockdown browser, I had to take a test on it, and it completely locks your computer until you exit

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `unload` event ? (`<body onunload="myfunc()">` or http://api.jquery.com/unload/ )

Comment: is there any way to trap also the try again button and resend? i've tried so many codes and it works but it all allow you to try again and resend..

Comment: i already solve the back button issue.. the problem is the refreshing of the page.. can you help me guys?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the solution should rely on a client-side code because it can be modified by the client. I think it could be okay for some kind of controlled environment where you can prevent the client from entering in developer mode.

In case the environment can be controlled, restricting keyboard shortcut, right click and providing a browser in full-screen mode should be enough to ensure the client complete the task properly.

Otherwise, a system relying on key/value token between the client a server should do the job. Some secure online service rely on such system and it works well if you accept to broke the "back" and "forward" functionality as well as the refresh page. You surely could emulate a callback when the client call such broken functionality.

There is some circumstance in which it's useful to only on JavaScript to ensure page display. Such as generating random identifier and random so the page never the same, etc.

In any case (IMO), exclusively relying on JavaScript for security purpose is not (and never) a good idea.

**Edit:**

Here is a  Proof-Of-Concept:

The server generate a uniqid and the client store that value using html5 local storage functionality. Using the local storage as a key/value registry we can store the page stage and compare each reload with the stored key compared with the server new generated key.

It's pretty straight-forward and what used as the server generated token can be randomize a lot, preventing anyone from guessing it.

A long enough server generated token could even provide a good single-use encryption key for the client local storage registry.

Code:

```
<?php   
    $stamp = uniqid();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{background-color:blue;}
        p{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:800px;background-color:gray;font-weight:bolder;padding:1em;}
    </style>
    <script>
    // display nice messages
    var err_reloaded_page = "page reloaded";

    var keeper = '<?php echo $stamp; ?>';
    var current = $.jStorage.get('state');
        // first initialization, Exception
        if(current ==  null){
            $.jStorage.set('state',keeper);
            current = $.jStorage.get('state');
        }

        if(current != keeper){
            alert(err_reloaded_page);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Proof of concept<br/>
        Can detect page reload by comparing a stamp created server-side, stored on the local storage and compared on each page reload.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many browsers have a 'kiosk mode' similar to what you're suggesting.

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript">
 function changeHashOnLoad() {
        window.location.href += "#";
        setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50");
    }

    function changeHashAgain() 
    {          
        window.location.href += "1";
    }

    var storedHash = window.location.hash;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
            window.location.hash = storedHash;
        }
    }, 50);

    </script>

Comment: I've tried this javascript code but it only expires the document and when you click the try again and resend the page will repeat the previous page.

Comment: I'm guessing that any browser new enough to support HTML5 Localstorage won't need the json library.

Comment: i already solve the back button issue.. the problem is the refreshing of the page.. can you help me guys?

Comment: it is possible for you to implement a solution using php?

Comment: are you asking me if i can give a solution using php?

Comment: yes and I just added the code to complete the proof of concept, had too many issue so add it as a new answer, in an image cause the system won't let me post the code otherwise. maybe it's time for me to go to sleep, good night

Comment: I updated my answer to include a coding example, so it be more practical and less theoretical. It works but I think it worth mentioning the key/value is an idea and the code an example. uniqid can be guessed, anyway, I think you get my point.